# how to combine PolicyInjection.Create and UnityContainer.RegisterType?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, enterprise-library

My web application uses UnityContainer.

I want to add Policy injection.

How can I use both of them side by side?

meaning who should be responsible of the types registration?

policy injsection:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = PolicyInjection.Create<TestModel, ITestModel>();

        ViewBag.Message = model.TestLog();

        return View();
    }
```

unity:

```
 IUnityContainer container = defaultContainer;

                //registering Unity for MVC
                DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

                //registering Unity for web API
                //  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);

                #region managers
                container.RegisterType<ISettingsManager, SettingsManager>();

                container.RegisterType<IMamDataManager, MamDataManager>();

                container.RegisterType<IAppsDataManager, AppsDataManager>();
                #endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unity 2.0 integrates Policy injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660915%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx). You don't have to use the static `PolicyInjection` class any longer.

---

**Update**

There is an [article by Dino Esposito](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/gg598927.aspx) that contains some good examples.

Comment: @EladBenda The article that is linked in my update contains some examples

Comment: is `// Policy injection` needed? what's `Fluent Code` ?

Comment: @EladBenda You need to add the `Interception` extension to the container and the `PolicyInjectionBehavior` and an `Interceptor` to the registration of every Type you want to intercept. Fluent code means the configuration style. You can see a sample on how to use the config file later in the article.